# Is there a metric space such that every Cauchy sequence in it does not converge?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose we have a metric space $(X,d)$, can $x_n \to x' $ as $n\to \infty$ such that $x'\notin X$ for any Cauchy sequence if the interior of $X$ is nonempty?

My logic: if $X$ has nonempty interior, then we can define a constant sequence $x_n = x$ with $x\in X$. And this constant sequence is Cauchy obviously. Hence, there is no such metric space.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: Yes: you are correct. All constant sequences must converge, and are obviously Cauchy.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say $x_n \rightarrow x'$ if $x' \notin X$ unless we are considering $X$ as a subset of some larger space.

Comment: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. $X$ is discrete iff Cauchy sequences in $X$ converge only when they are eventually constant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right. No such **non-empty** metric space exists. Let $(X,d)$ be an arbitrary non-empty metric space.

Fix $x \in X$ and define a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ by $x_n:= x, n \geq 1$. Then clearly $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$ and the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a convergent/Cauchy sequence.

But what happens when $X = \emptyset$?

Then vacuously, every Cauchy sequence  in $X$ does NOT converge (but also converges!). So the only such metric space is the empty metric space.

Comment: Wow the last statement is so weird. I immediately thought it was a contradiction, but I guess its not.

Comment: Haha yes, you can say that every Cauchy sequence in the empty set both converges and not converges.

Comment: +1 for the beautiful last paragraph!